# Gatsby Pagination for multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Most of the Gatsby tutorials I've seen deal with one single source of pagination. For my site, I have multiple pages that use GraphQL to filter different categories of 160+ of blog posts. I need some way to paginate each category page, so users don't have to scroll down dozens of articles to reach the site footer. But solutions online like `gatsby-awesome-pagination` deal with a single source of pagination.

Is it possible to have pagination across multiple pages? I imagine I'd have to customize the GraphQL of each category page to account for the difference in blog posts for each page required for pagination? Is this idea even possible?

My [Github](https://github.com/develijahlee/yonseiuicscribe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit the nail, you need to custom your page creation. In your `gatsby-node.js`

```
  const posts = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
  const postsPerPage = 6
  const numPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage)
  Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? `/blog` : `/blog/${i + 1}`,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/blog-list-template.js"),
      context: {
        limit: postsPerPage,
        skip: i * postsPerPage,
        numPages,
        currentPage: i + 1,
      },
    })
  })
```

The code above will create an amount of pages that is based on the total number of posts. Each page will list `postsPerPage(6)` posts, until there are less than `postsPerPage(6)` posts left. The path for the first page is `/blog`, the following pages will have a path of the form: `/blog/2`, `/blog/3`, etc.

Keep in mind that you are passing via context the limit and the current page to your template. So, in your blog template your query should look like:

```
  query blogListQuery($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      limit: $limit
      skip: $skip
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You are all done, you only need to add the next and prev buttons/numbering in your component with something like this:

**Next/Prev buttons:**

```
  const { currentPage, numPages } = this.props.pageContext
    const isFirst = currentPage === 1
    const isLast = currentPage === numPages
    const prevPage = currentPage - 1 === 1 ? "/" : (currentPage - 1).toString()
    const nextPage = (currentPage + 1).toString()
    return (
       /* your code to display a list of posts */
      {!isFirst && (
        <Link to={prevPage} rel="prev">
          ← Previous Page
        </Link>
      )}
      {!isLast && (
        <Link to={nextPage} rel="next">
          Next Page →
        </Link>
      )}
    )
```

**Numbering:**

```
   const { currentPage, numPages } = this.props.pageContext
    return (
      // ...
      {Array.from({ length: numPages }, (_, i) => (
        <Link key={`pagination-number${i + 1}`} to={`/${i === 0 ? "" : i + 1}`}>
          {i + 1}
        </Link>
      ))}
```

You can check for further details [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-pagination/).

Comment: I have a question on `component: path.resolve("./src/templates/blog-list-template.js"),` Because my website structure uses multiple category pages that query different `frontmatter` I'm confused how to resolve a single path for multiple different queries. Right now my posts are being sourced from `component: path.resolve(./src/templates/blog-post.js),` that use `markdownRemark` so it's very tricky for me use the following suggestion. Is there an alternative way to use a component instead of a template? Then I could share that component with my category pages.

Comment: You should create the same structure (the loop setting maximum post/tags/whatever per page) because the code runs `onCreatePage` API so, Gatsby must know how many items per page must be. What you can reuse is the pagination component, you can extract them and import it, passing via props what you need to custom 1 component in multiple uses.

Comment: The gatsby site suggestion of blog-list template using `allMarkdownRemark` isn't very suitable for me as my blog-list template does not have a single source, but are slightly different graphQL queries running on 9 different pages. There isn't really a blog-list template for me to query in this case. I just have a blog-post template that spits out `markdownRemark` html. I hope I'm making sense. This is my first gatsby project and I'm a little clueless on what's really possible or not.

Comment: Ok so I will try to create a pagination component and set the path.resolve to that component and import it into the other category pages. I'm not sure about what I should pass via props but will try to figure it out as I go.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the structure of your project, I think it is more a problem of structure and how Gatsby works rather than code. You should pass via props all the component needs (which in fact is almost all your context, i.e: maximum number of items, current page, limit, etc).

Comment: Ok I will try thank you. As this is my first gatsby project I'm not sure if I'm even explaining things correctly. For now I will make a separate blog-list-template page and run the code as you've suggested.

Comment: Keep me posted. I would suggest you try pagination for a single category (post or whatever) and then upgrade it to tags, posts, and other sources.

Comment: Hi I was wondering if you could look over my attempted solution? To have pagination, I want to refactor all my pages to output code from a blog-list-template. But since it is a template, I need someway to dynamically change the query for each category page. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61136694/how-to-pass-graphql-query-as-a-react-prop]

Comment: Nvm just read that StaticQuery does not accept variables, will have to try another solution

Comment: Thanks for the update.  StaticQuery doesn't accept two invokes in the same component either. I'm afraid you should try a kind of middleware in order to firstly get and retrieve all post from sources and then tackle the pagination. Good luck.