# How is Gatsby Blog List pagination rendered?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Reading the pagination tutorial, I don't understand how the pagination is rendered? Which page is being used? Is the `blog-list-template` a component being passed onto a file in a page folder? If not, then how does gatsby know to use the `blog-list-template` when there isn't a file specified?

The [Tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-pagination/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gatsby Pagination for multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101895/gatsby-pagination-for-multiple-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial example, look at the code for `gatsby-node.js`.

```
const path = require("path")
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // 1.
  const result = await graphql(
    `
      {
        allMarkdownRemark(
          sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
          limit: 1000
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              fields {
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }

  // ...

  // Create blog-list pages
  const posts = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
  const postsPerPage = 6
  const numPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage)

  // 2.
  Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    createPage({
      // 4. 
      path: i === 0 ? `/blog` : `/blog/${i + 1}`,

      // 3.
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/blog-list-template.js"),
      context: {
        limit: postsPerPage,
        skip: i * postsPerPage,
        numPages,
        currentPage: i + 1,
      },
    })
  })
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}
```

1. First it will query `allMarkdownRemark`.
2. Then it will create an amount of pages that is based on the total number of posts found by the above query using `createPage`.
3. It creates each page using `blog-list-template` and some information about pagination in the page's `context`. (Note that as a result, `$skip` & `$limit` are then available to be used as variables in `blog-list-template`'s graphql query.)

Each page will list 6 posts, until there are less than 6 posts left (`const postsPerPage = 6`).

4. The path for the first page is `/blog`, following pages will have a path of the form: `/blog/2`, `/blog/3`, etc.